# How to color parameters in VScode in the declaration method and the body

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can not make see that the parameters of the methods are of a certain color in the body too.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {

  "textMateRules": [
    {
      "scope": "variable.parameter.ts, variable.other.object.ts",
      "settings": {
        "foreground":"#f00"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

If you examine your variables with the palette command `Developer: Inspect TM Scopes` you will see that both of your instances are `variable`s but so are many other things.  You can narrow down your scope with the two scopes I used above to achieve what you want.

[image: textmate scope example]

Comment: No luck.. The same. In some places works in others no :(.

Comment: Can you show an example where it doesn't work.  Hard to help without an example where it isn't working now.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine in the function declaration:

- Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>comma</kbd>
- from the top right menu, click on curly braces. (`settings.json` file)
- Add the following settings:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
      {
        "scope": "variable.parameter",
        "settings": {
          "fontStyle": "",
          "foreground":"#413f39"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Sorry but it dont work.. The parameters in the body takes normal color.

Comment: @JuanPedroMolina This actually works on my vscode... What's your OS?

Comment: This probably depends on the language. Vscode might support it only for some languages.

Comment: Windows 10 at TypeScript  @amirali

Comment: @HolyBlackCat TypeScript.

Answer (score 0):

There are two conditions for successful coloring:

1. The language must support semantic parsing.
2. The current theme must contains

   "semanticHighlighting": true